# How to update a column with multiple values in single query

Tags: sql

Example

```
Update A 
set userid - (1, 2, 3), userrolesid - (1, 2, 3) 
where id - 40
```

Comment: which sql database and how do you mean by updating multiple values in a column?

Answer (score 0):

Use below query for multiple update :

```
  UPDATE A SET userid = '1,2,3' , userrolesid = '1,2,3'
  WHERE id = 40
```

Note : Both update columns must be in VARCHAR data type.

Comment: Correct it to `id = 40`.

Comment: @aendeerei,Thanks

Comment: Its int datatype

Comment: @Siva,If datatype is int you cannot store multiple values at userid , userrolesid column.Change your datatype or store single single value.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH Tmp(id, px, py) AS (VALUES(id1, newsPosX1, newPosY1), 
                               (id2, newsPosX2, newPosY2),
                               ......................... ,
                               (idN, newsPosXN, newPosYN))

UPDATE TableToUpdate 
SET posX = (SELECT px
            FROM Tmp
            WHERE TableToUpdate.id = Tmp.id),
    posY = (SELECT py
            FROM Tmp
            WHERE TableToUpdate.id = Tmp.id)
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM Tmp)
```

Comment: how did you come up with an answer like this while the OP is as simple as updating a field?